# Restart foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array with products as objects in it. Each object contains a key = category_title

I have a foreach loop that generates products in Bootstrap rows with configurable columns, in my case `$col=3`.

What I need is to have a new row if a new category_title comes up.

I created an array to push all the `category_titles` in it and create a variable if it is a new category. But now I am stuck.

The foreach looks like this:

```
<?php foreach($productspercat as $product):         ?>


            <!-- Make sure product is enabled and visible @front end -->
            <?php //  if($product->enabled && $product->visibility):?>
                <?php

                    $catnew = false;
                $categorytitle = $product->category_title;
                if(!in_array($categorytitle, $totalcategories, true)):?>
                    <?php               array_push($totalcategories,$categorytitle );
                    $catnew=true;
            ?>
                <?php endif;?>
```

```
                    <div class="j2store-products-row <?php echo 'row-'.$row; ?> row">
                    <?php endif;?>

                    <div class="col-sm-<?php echo round((12 / $col));?>">
                        <h2><?php echo $categorytitle; ;
                        var_dump($catnew);
                        ?></h2>
                        test
                    </div>
            <?php $counter++;
            $firstrun = true; ?>
            <?php if (($rowcount == $col) or ($counter == $total)) : ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php // endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

So basically if a new category comes up, it should close the row and start a fresh row with a new column count.

appreciate any help!

Comment: Easy: Don't use `foreach()`. It's not designed to be restarted, but with a regular `for` loop you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to page refresh then you can do that by using jQuery or Angular JS. 
By jQuery you can add data by jquery prepend() function if you wanna add data in starting or append() function to add ending section.

Comment: there must be a way to do this in the php-script. only i am a php-newbie. I am sure the answer is quite simple, but my brains hurts from all the possibilities

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
// Arranged products by category title
$arrangedProducts = array()
foreach($productspercat as $product) {
    if (!array_key_exists($product->category_title, $arrangedProducts)) {
        $arrangedProducts[$product->category_title] = array();
    }

    $arrangedProducts[$product->category_title][] = $product;
}

// each category is a key and its value is an array with all its products
foreach ($arrangedProducts as $categoryTitle => $products) {
    // you create a new row
    // ....
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        // you display product information
    }

    // you end the row
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you!
for some reason I now get only 1 row with the same product in 3 columns.

Comment: the thing is it should create rows as long as there are products in the category, that's what the $col is for. it counts the columns and after (in my case 3), it starts a new row. 
this should stay the same within each category, only ist should break a row, if there is less products left (for instance there are only 2 products in the category) it should break the routine and start a new row. If I understand your code correctly it would create a row per category which is not quite correct.

Comment: I got it! I had to reset the counter in the outer foreach, and now it is working!!
thank you, you are my hero!!